# How to automate Fuzz operation in ZAP?

Tags: zap, fuzzing, security-testing

I know there is zapv2 library, but how could I automate Fuzz in zapv2 ?

Is it possible to use zapv2 to locate a fuzz file ? and trigger fuzzer scan ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the ZAP API does not currently support fuzzing. We do plan to add it and have an open bug for this: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/1689

Comment: Are there any updates on fuzzing support in latest version of Y2022 on zap?

Comment: See the above issue, ie "no" :)